# Number of teams that can be formed subject to the condition that A will work on the team only if B also works on the team

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

In an organization there are 11 people A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K.  Four members from these 11 people are supposed to work on a project. How many distinct four persons team can be chosen such that the following condition is met "A will work on the team only if B is also working on the team".

If we divide it into cases

1. A and B are fixed, so 9c2
2. A is not in the team but B is in team so 9c3
   so 9c2+9c3=120

Is it correct? Please verify.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question by means of an edit (not a comment), and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: There is a third case that satisfies the requirements: neither A nor B is on the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**  The condition that A will work on the team only if B is also working on the team is satisfied if

- both A and B are on the team
- B is on the team, but A is not
- neither A nor B is on the team

You overlooked the third case.

*Both A and B are on the team*:  Then two of the other nine people must be selected to be on the team, which can be done in
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{9}{2} = \binom{9}{2}$$
ways, as you found.

*B is on the team, but A is not*:  Then three of the other nine people must be selected to be on the team, which can be done in
$$\binom{1}{0}\binom{1}{1}\binom{9}{3} = \binom{9}{3}$$
ways, as you found.

*Neither A nor B is on the team*:  Then four of the other nine people must be selected to be on the team, which can be done in
$$\binom{2}{0}\binom{9}{4} = \binom{9}{4}$$
ways.

*Total*:  Since the three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of teams that can be formed subject to the constraint that A will work on the team only if B is also working on the team is
$$\binom{9}{2} + \binom{9}{3} + \binom{9}{4}$$

**Method 2:** The condition that A will work on the team only if B is also working on the team is satisfied unless A is on the team, but B is not.

If there were no restrictions, we could select four of the eleven people to work on the team in
$$\binom{11}{4}$$
ways.

If A is on the team, but B is not, then we must select three of the other nine people, which can be done in
$$\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{0}\binom{9}{3} = \binom{9}{3}$$
ways.

Hence, the number of admissible teams is
$$\binom{11}{4} - \binom{9}{3}$$